# Creating generic child packages in Ada 95

Tags: generics, package, ada

I have package `p1` and two child packages: `p1.child1` and `p1.child2`
All packages are generic. I'm trying to create an instance of `p1.child1` in `p1.child2`:

```
package body p1inst.child2 is

   package p1inst is new p1;
   use p1inst;

   package p1_child1inst is new p1inst.child1;
   use p1inst;
```

I got an error: `Instansiation of "p1" within itself`.
How can I create an instance of generic package `p1.child2` into `p1.child1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in [*Ada Programming: Advanced generics*](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Generics#Advanced_generics), it may help to distinguish between a generic unit and an *instance* of that generic unit. The compiler is telling you that you can't create an instance of `p1` in a child of `p1`, because "Children of a generic unit *must* be generic, no matter what."

Instead, create an instance of `p1` elsewhere, and use that instance to create an instance of each of the children of `p1`.

Addendum: As another concrete example, [`procedure Jumble`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/jumbleada) creates an instance of [`Ada.Strings.Bounded`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-4-4.html):

```
Max_Word  : constant Positive := 24;
package ASB is new Ada.Strings.Bounded.Generic_Bounded_Length(Max_Word);
```

Later, the procedure uses that instance to create an instance of the generic child, [`Ada.Strings.Bounded.Hash`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-4-9.html):

```
function Hash is new Ada.Strings.Bounded.Hash(ASB);
```